# findBy UUID field always return null . ( MySQL + JAVA + Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In my project, one of the object's fields is UUID ( Java.util.uuid )
when I try to use find by(Myfield) its always returns null, even though the object exists.

I adding my code and example to clearly the problem :

My entity :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "RH_item_id")
private int item_id;

@Column(name = "RH_order_id")
private int orderId;

@Column(name = "RH_partner_order_id",columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
@Type(type = "uuid-binary")
private UUID partnerOrderId;
```

my repository :

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {

List<Transaction> findByDate(Date date);

List<Transaction> findByAgent(Agent agent);

List<Transaction> findByFreelancer(Freelancer freelancer);

List<Transaction> findByStatus(Status status);

Transaction findByPartnerOrderId(UUID id);

Transaction findByOrderId(int id);

List<Transaction> findByEmail(String email);
```

}

my controller to check the repository :
public class AgentController {

```
@Autowired
private AgentService agentService;

@Autowired
private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_AGENT')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllTrans", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTransactions() {
    try {
        List<Transaction> Lot = agentService.getAllTransactions();
        System.out.println(transactionRepository.findByPartnerOrderId(Lot.get(4).getPartnerOrderId()));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(Lot);
    } catch (TransactionsNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("There are no transactions found.");
}
```

If you notice even though I get the field from the object itself (Lot) it returns me null. ( transactionRepository.findByPartnerOrderId(Lot.get(4).getPartnerOrderId() )

It doesn't make any sense ...

Anyone can help me?  I guess the problem must come from the hibernate itself maybe he doesn't know to read UUID from the MYSQL DB.

Comment: I think UUID is getting stored as binary but when you query, hibernate is not applying this conversion. Try doing UUID->Binary before passing the query to DB

Comment: what you mean ? what should I try to do ? give me an example please .

Answer (score 0):

You can add log to your app

```
# logs the SQL statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

and watch sql with params it used.

What kind of coulmn type used for uuid in db?

Comment: I will try it . the columns type mention in the post : @Type(type = "uuid-binary")

Comment: Hibernate generate table for you? Show the logs